# Homebrewでclangをinstallしようとするとerror

Tags: homebrew, clang

http://tkymx83.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/04/03/231642
ここを参考にHome brewでclangをinstallしたいのですが

```
$ brew install clang

Error: No available formula with the name "clang"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
clang-format ✔                                       clang-format@3.8                                     emacs-clang-complete-async
To install one of them, run (for example):
brew install clang-format ✔
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

とエラーが出ます. どう対処したら良いでしょうか.

Comment: brew search clang
と
パッケージの検索をするとどんな結果が返ってきますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install llvm
```

で入りませんか？

Answer (score 1):

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ にある Homebrew の formula 一覧を見ると分かりますが、現在 `clang` という formula は無いので「見つからないよ」というエラーが出ています。

2018 年 7 月現在、代わりに `llvm` という formula が[提供されています](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/llvm)。Xcode の Apple Clang とどう共存させるかに応じて、`brew install llvm` または `brew install --with-toolchain llvm` でインストールすることができます。